# USB motherboard header pin spacing

Tags: usb, motherboard, connector

I have a asrock Z68 Extreme 4 (gen 1) motherboard. If you have a look at its manual ftp://europe.asrock.com/Manual/Z68%20Extreme4.pdf on page 13 you can notice that there are 3 usb 2.0 headers.

One of them though has clearly a narrower pin spacing, is this a standard? In particular I'm trying to find a cable that fits that pins, but this is turning out to be a real challenge, I don't even know the name of this connector.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

USB 3.0 uses the (only) 19pin connector on the motherboard. Several companies build "USB 3.0 mainboard connectors" e.g. Sharkoon art.no. 4044951012244, or delock art.no. 65670 (in Germany).

Note that there are 2 types of adapters: one 19pin connector yields 2 USB ports; both ports can be stacked on the wider side of the jacks (like Sharkoon's) or on the narrow side of the jacks (like delock's). The combination of adapter and mainboard is important as sometimes the wrong type of adaptor collides with components near the connector.

Comment: I'm referring to USB 2.0 headers with 9 pins. Some of them have a pitch of 2.54mm whereas others seem to have a shorter distance between pins equal to approximately 2mm.

Comment: Ah-ha. You could've made that clearer in your question, or I simply misunderstood it. Sorry, my answer then is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

First off are you sure this is not just a misprint in the manual, the photos i'm seeing of the board show a connector with standard-sized pins in that position (though without the outer plastic part that the other headers have).

If it is real then it  is just plain strange. 2mm square pin headers do exist but I've never seen anyone use them for USB 2 before.

You will probably be able to buy a suitable connector shell and pins from an electronics distributor like Farnell, RS, Mouser or Digikey but then you will need the crimp tool to attach it to a cable and it all gets a bit costly for a one-off. Also shopping for connectors is a PITA, every manufacturer names them differently. I find the best way to shop for connectors is to use the parametric search on a suppliers site (mouser, digikey, farnell, RS etc), select the pin spacing, number of pins and number of rows and then look through the pictures.